# Web scraping not getting complete source code data via Selenium/BS4

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

[image]

How do I scrape the data in the input tag's value attributes from the source I inspect as shown in image?

I have tried using BeautifulSoup and Selenium, and neither of them works for me.

Partial code is below:

```
html=driver.page_source

output=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#bookingForm > div:nth-child(1) > div.bookingType > div:nth-child(15) > div.col-md-9 > input').get_attribute("value")

print(output)
```

This returns a `NoSuchElementException` error.

In fact when I try to `print(html)`, a lot of source code data appear to be missing. I suspect it could be JS related issues, but Selenium - which works most of the time rendering JS - is not working for me on this site. Any idea why?

I tried these as well:

```
html=driver.page_source

soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

test = soup.find("input",{"class":"inputDisable"})

print(test)

print(soup)
```

`print(test)` returns `None`, and `print(soup)` returns the source with most input tags entirely missing.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this element is present on this site by inspecting the page.
If its there , many times selenium is too fast and the page sometimes doesn't manage to load completely.try the **WAIT** funtion of selenium.Many times thats the case.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("url")
delay = 3 # seconds
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'IdOfMyElement')))
    print "Page is ready!"
except TimeoutException:
    print "Loading took too much time!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `find` or `find_all` functions. (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'your url'
response = get(url)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
test = bs.find("input",{"class":"inputDisable"})

print(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import date



URL="https://yourUrl.com"

# Chrome session
driver = webdriver.Chrome("PathOfTheBrowserDriver")
driver.get(URL)
driver.implicitly_wait(100)
time.sleep(5)

soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
```

Try, BEFORE making the soup, to create a break with your code, in order to give the requests the to do their job (some late requests may contain what you're looking for)